# Certain fonts and Characters no being displayed

Tags: wordpress, fonts, cross-domain

I get the error:

Font from origin 'http://livehealthyme.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.livehealthyme.com' is therefore not allowed access. www.livehealthyme.com/:1

I think it is because I am using Ninja Firewall on my site. Is there a way to allow my fonts and still have my firewall up?

Comment: Can you not modify your font `src` to your domain with `www`?

Comment: How are you currently importing/loading the fonts?

Comment: They are in the fonts folder in the theme folder and its FontAwesome fonts but it doesn't seem to be pulling them.